# "non-blocking" Im Deutschen mit oder ohne Bindestrich?

Tags: english-to-german

Es gibt im Message Passing Interface (kurz MPI) blocking und non-blocking Operationen. Schreibt man im Deutschen dann, blockierende und nicht-blockierende Operationen? Oder doch ohne Bindestrich "nicht blockierende" Operationen?

Gibt es eigentlich eine Regel für den Einsatz des Bindestriches?

Comment: Es gibt sogar sieben Seiten mit Regeln dazu. :-) ([Seiten 45 bis 51](http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de/download/regeln2006.pdf))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Der Bindestrich sollte verwendet werden, um Wörter zu *verbinden*, die ansonsten auch zusammen-geschrieben oder zusammen gehören würden. Er kann damit zur Hervorhebung der beiden Bestandteile dienen.
Im Gegensatz zu Subjektiven (**Nichtwähler, Nichtbeachtung**) geht bei Adjektiven und Verben (**nichtamtliche Verlautbarung, nichteuropäische Einwanderer**) die Tendenz zur Getrenntschreibung (und nicht Getrennt Schreibung oder Getrennt-Schreibung).

Im Grunde sind aber derzeit alle drei Versionen erlaubt:

- **nichtblockierend** (klassisch)
- **nicht-blockierend** (mit Bindestrich zur Hervorhebung)
- **nicht blockierend** (modern)

Die Verneinung eines Adjektivs ist in meinem Sprachgefühl der "gestochenen" oder amtlichen Formulierung vorbehalten. Man versucht doch eher das Gegenteil zu finden(, sofern es genau eines gibt, wie bei **nichtvolljährig** = **minderjährig** oder **nichtfachmännisch** = **laienhaft**,) oder die Vorsilbe "un-" zu verwenden (damit es nicht un-verständlich wird).

Bei Übersetzungen spräche demnach auch nichts dagegen, Neuschöpfungen zu schaffen, wie "**blockierend** - **durchlaufend**,  **freilaufend** oder **entkoppelt**", ganz entsprechend dem mechanischen Bild. Zugegebenermaßen würde das im Programmiererumfeld wohl zunächst leicht aufstoßen.

Comment: Apropos vermeiden, man spricht in diesem Fall (auch im Englischen) oft von _synchron_ (wartet, bis etwas passiert ist) und _asynchron_ (wartet nicht).

Comment: Ja, tut man; obwohl es das in diesem Fall nicht so gut beschreibt, weil ein synchroner Zugriff (gerade im Deutschen) zunächst als *gleichzeitig* verstanden werden sollte. Am Telefon antworte ich besser nicht synchron meinem Anrufer, obwohl ich Mails immer asynchron beantworten muss (und glücklicherweise auch kann).

Comment: Wieso schreibst Du Bindestrich und Programmiererumfeld mit Bindestrich? Soll das witzig sein?

Comment: @chirlu non-blocking impliziert nicht immer asynchron. eine andere möglichkeit wäre z.B. eine Exception.

Comment: Ich würde irgendwie weder bei "durchlaufend", noch bei "freilaufend", noch bei "entkoppelt" verstehen, dass "nicht blockierend" gemeint ist.

Comment: Zudem empfinde ich irgendwie einen Unterschied zwischen der zusammengeschriebenen und der getrennten Schreibweise. Bei binären Angaben wie "blockierend" ist dieser irrelevant, aber bei kontinuierlichen Werten würde ich so etwas wie "nichtschön" als eine Umschreibung für "hässlich" verstehen, während "nicht schön" alles abdeckt, was einfach nicht schön ist (aber nicht zwangsläufig hässlich, beispielsweise auch einfach neutral).

Comment: Der Binde-Strich war dazu gedacht, das *verbinden* hervorzuheben, @userunknown. Aber das hat schon ein Besserwisser wegverbessert.

Comment: "Nichtschön" (oder gewöhnlich "unschön") ist nicht gleichbedeutend mit dem Gegenteil von schön, @O.R.Mapper. Das geht vor allem bei Wörtern nicht, die kein Gegenteil haben ("nicht grün"). Daher die Bemerkung "*versucht* […] Gegenteil zu finden".

Comment: Noch @O.R.Mapper: Wer sich einigermaßen mit Fahrrädern auskennt, versteht auch Freilauf, im Gegensatz zur starren Nabe von Einrad oder Kunstrad. Ich finde das einen recht guten Vergleich zum Systemaufruf, bei dem der aufrufende Prozess frei weiterlaufen kann und nicht im Rhythmus des Betriebssystem mittreten muss.

Comment: @Dirk: Ok, kein Themengebiet, zu dem ich mich hingezogen fühle, weshalb mir wohl auch der Begriff "Freilauf" unbekannt war. Ich pflichte dir bei, dass es da wohl eine gewisse Analogie gibt.