# Bindestrich vs. Zusammenschreibung bei Mehrwortanglizismen

Tags: spelling, anglicism

Gibt es allgemeine Empfehlungen/Regeln für das Zusammenschreiben oder Setzen eines Bindestrichs für Anglizismen, die aus mehreren Einzelwörtern bestehen?

Hängt es eher davon ab, wie sich der spezielle Begriff eingebürgert hat?

Macht es einen Unterschied, ob die Wörter mit zusätzlichen Wortbestandteilen kombiniert werden?

Beispiele:

- Car Sharing vs. Car-Sharing vs. CarSharing vs. Carsharing
- (analog Bike-Sharing)
- Worst Case vs Worst-Case-Szenario
- Use Case vs. Use Case Diagramm vs. Use Case-Diagramm vs. Use-Case-Diagramm
- Turn-Key-Lösung vs. Turnkey-Lösung
- Modal Split

Unabhängig davon, dass man die meisten Anglizismen durch handliche deutsche Begriffe ersetzen kann (insb. "turn-key" scheint eher ein ins Englische übersetztes "schlüsselfertig" zu sein, als ein Anglizismus), scheint es, von relativ eindeutig etablierten Kombinationen abgesehen (wie Modal Split), relativ egal zu sein, wie mans macht.

Ähnliche Fragen:

- [Zusammengesetzes Wort: Bindestrich oder nicht?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/5222) -- Bezieht sich auf deutsche Komposita
- ["non-blocking" Im Deutschen mit oder ohne Bindestrich?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/25113) -- bezieht sich auf die Übersetzung "nichtblockierend"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Die offiziellen Rechtschreibregeln wissen dazu (§45, E1, $45, E2):

> Aus  anderen  Sprachen  stammende  Verbindungen  aus  Substantiv  + 
>   Substantiv,  die  sich  im  Deutschen  grammatisch  wie  Zusammensetzungen 
>   verhalten,  werden  zusammengeschrieben;  ebenso  ist  die  verdeutlichende 
>   Schreibung  mit  Bindestrich  möglich:
>
> - Sexappeal (Sex-Appeal),
> - Sciencefiction  (Science-Fiction),
> - Shoppingcenter   (Shopping-Center),
> - Desktoppublishing  (Desktop-Publishing),
> - Midlifecrisis (Midlife-Crisis)

Demnach hieße es wohl *Carsharing* oder alternativ *Car-Sharing*. Ich meine, dass sich die zusammengeschriebene Variante eher durchgesetzt hat.

Handelt es sich nicht um Bildungen aus Substantiven oder Substantivierungen, gilt E2:

> Aus dem Englischen stammende Substantivierungen aus Verb + Adverb 
>   schreibt  man  mit  Bindestrich;  **das  Adverb  wird  dann  kleingeschrieben**,  zum Beispiel: 
>   -Make-up, 
>   -Go-in
>
> Daneben ist auch Zusammenschreibung möglich, sofern die Lesbarkeit nicht 
>   beeinträchtigt   ist,   zum   Beispiel:
>
> -Count-down (Countdown),
>
> -Come-back (Comeback),
>
> -Knock-out (Knockout),
>
> -Stand-by (Standby)

Zu zusammengesetzten Begriffen mit Adjektiv + Substantiv weiß man folgendes:

> Aus  dem  Englischen  stammende Bildungen  aus  Adjektiv  +  Substantiv 
>   können zusammengeschrieben werden, wenn der Hauptakzent auf dem ersten Bestandteil liegt, also 
>   -Hotdog oder Hot Dog,
>
> -Softdrink oder Soft Drink, aber nur
>
> -High Society,
>
> -Electronic Banking oder
>
> -New Economy.

(Man beachte, dass es für die Kombination dieser Wortarten keine 
"Bindestricherlaubnis" gibt.

Als letztes gibt es noch die Gruppe der "stark eingedeutschten Zusammensetzungen", für die man folgendes weiß:

> Dieser Regel [Zusammenschreibung] folgen auch lexikalisierte, ursprünglich aus dem Englischen stammende  bzw.  aus  englischen  Einheiten  gebildete  Zusammensetzungen: Bandleader, Cheerleader, Chewinggum,Mountainbike, Bluejeans, Hardware, Swimmingpool.

Deine ganze Liste damit:

- Carsharing oder Car-Sharing
- Bike-Sharing oder Bikesharing
- Worst Case und Worst-Case-Szenario
- Usecase oder Use-Case
- Usecasediagramm oder (eher) Use-Case-Diagramm
- Turn-Key-Lösung oder Turnkeylösung
- Modal Split

Comment: Die *offiziellen* Regeln geben "Sciencefiction" oder "Sexappeal" als den *Normalfall* an?? Das scheint mir ziemlich realitätsfern.

Comment: @KilianFoth Frag' ngrams. *Sexappeal* ist seit 2000 ungefähr 10 x häufiger als *Sex-Appeal*

Answer (score 1):

Bei Anglizismen gibt es grundsätzlich die Möglichkeiten, das Wort englisch oder deutsch zu schreiben.

- Wird das Wort englisch geschrieben, werden die englischen Regeln befolgt: Kleinschreibung und Worttrennung sind der Regelfall
- Deutsch geschriebene Wörte sind (gegebenenfalls) großgeschrieben und entweder zusammengezogen oder mit Bindestrichen getrennt.

Es ist also Carsharing oder Car-Sharing oder car sharing. Niemals Car Sharing, CarSharing oder car-sharing.

Comment: Abgesehen davon, dass es den Rechtschreibregeln (vgl. @tofros Antwort) widerspricht, wäre das sehr merkwürdig. Verallgemeinert hieße der erste Punkt ja, dass man bei jedem Wort aus einer Fremdsprache die entsprechende Grammatik und Orthographie dieser Sprache beherrschen müsste.

Comment: Oder die deutsche.

Comment: Wie wär's mit *Kahrschähring*?

Comment: Karschäring ist nur nach Gründonnerstag erlaubt